# Primitive of $\int \frac{dx}{ x \sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c}}$ for negative discriminant $b^2 - 4 a c < 0$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm having problems with this primitive in the real number domain:

Where $x \ne 0$ and $a x^2 + b x + c > 0$:

$$\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {x \sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} }$$
for $b^2 - 4 a c < 0$

According to item $14.283$ in Spiegel's "Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables" (Schaum, 1968) it should work out as:

$$\dfrac {-1} {\sqrt c} {\sinh^{-1} } {\dfrac {b x + 2 c} {|x| \sqrt {4 a c - b^2} } }$$

or in an alternative form:

$$\dfrac {-1} {\sqrt c} {\arcsin^{-1} } {\dfrac {b x + 2 c} {|x| \sqrt {b^2 - 4 a c} } }$$

(ignoring the arbitrary constant of integration, to minimise clutter).

Now I can't work out where the absolute value operator comes in on the $x$.

I have got this far:

$x = \dfrac 1 u$

$\leadsto \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {\mathrm d u} = \dfrac {-1} {u^2}$

$\leadsto \displaystyle \int \frac {\mathrm d x} {x \sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} } = \int {\dfrac 1 {\dfrac 1 u \sqrt {a \left({\frac 1 u}\right)^2 + b \left({\frac 1 u}\right) + c} } } \dfrac {-\, \mathrm d u} {u^2}$

(by integration by substitution)

$= -\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\mathrm d u} {\frac {u^2} u \sqrt {\frac 1 {u^2} (a + b u + c u^2) } }$

$= -\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\mathrm d u} {\sqrt {a + b u + c u^2} }$

as those $u$ factors all cancel.

Then there is a standard result:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac {\mathrm d u} {\sqrt {a + b u + c u^2} } = \begin {cases}
\dfrac {-1} {\sqrt c} \ln \left\vert {2 \sqrt c \sqrt {a + b u + c u^2} + 2 c u + b}\right\vert + C & : b^2 - 4 a c > 0 \\
\dfrac {-1} {\sqrt c} \sinh^{-1} \left({\dfrac {2 c u + b} {\sqrt{4 a c - b^2} } }\right) + C & : b^2 - 4 a c < 0 \\
\dfrac {-1} {\sqrt c} \ln |2 c u + b| + C & : b^2 - 4 a c = 0
\end {cases}$

I'm only interested in the case where $b^2 - 4 a c < 0$.

Anyway, I substitute back the $u = \dfrac 1 x$ and after algebra I work it out to be:

$= \sinh^{-1} \left({\dfrac {b x + 2 c} {x \sqrt{4 a c - b^2} } }\right)$

Taking a step back I can't see where the $|x|$ would come from in Spiegel's result. Because $\sinh^{-1}$ is a bijection over the reals, an odd function continuous at $0$, there should be no discontinuity in the derivative, so the $|x|$ puzzles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this place: You have
$$\frac {u^2} u \sqrt {\frac 1 {u^2} (a + b u + c u^2) } =  \sqrt {a + b u + c u^2} $$
It is not true. It should be
$$\frac {u^2} u \sqrt {\frac 1 {u^2} (a + b u + c u^2) } =  \pm\sqrt {a + b u + c u^2}. $$

Answer (score 2):

Note that, under the condition $b^2-4ac <0$, the integral is defined for all real $x\ne 0$. The appearance of $|x|$ in the solution accommodates all domain of $x$, which can be seen in the derivation below. For $c>0$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac {1} {x \sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} }dx\\
=& \ \frac1{\sqrt c}\int \frac{\frac{2c}{x\sqrt{x^2}}}{\sqrt{4ac+\frac{4bc}{x}+\frac{4c^2}{x^2}}}dx
 = \frac1{\sqrt c}\int \frac{-d(\frac {bx+2c}{\sqrt{x^2}})}{\sqrt{(\frac {bx+2c}{\sqrt{x^2}})^2+{4ac-b^2}}}\\
=&- \frac1{\sqrt c}\sinh^{-1}\frac{bx+2c}{\sqrt{x^2(4ac-b^2)}}+C
\end{align}
The integral can also be evaluated to
\begin{align}\int \frac {1} {x \sqrt {a x^2 + b x + c} }dx
=-\frac1{\sqrt c}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\frac b2 x+c}{\sqrt c \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}+C
\end{align}
in order to avoid dealing with $|x|$.